# Autodesk Forge API not converting 3D model elements

Tags: unity-game-engine, autodesk-forge

We are having issues with our app since yesterday not converting model elements into Unity as an OBJ file.

Were there any changes released this weekend? We were able to do conversions last Thursday with no issues.

We have yet to pinpoint the issue where the app is converting the SVF from BIM 360 DOCs to an OBJ file we use in Unity.

The NWD is viewable in BIM 360 DOCs and the file and data convert fine, yet we do not have any 3D model elements in our viewer.

Any help or direction in this matter would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Is it an issue with the translation itself (i.e., the Model Derivative service fails to generate the OBJ), or with the downloading of the OBJ result?

Please note that recently the Model Derivative service had to decrease the maximum allowed size of a "derivative" that could be downloaded in one piece, as large derivative downloads were putting a lot of strain on the servers. If your OBJs are large, consider downloading them "in chunks" using the [HEAD   :urn/manifest/:derivativeurn](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-HEAD/) endpoint and the [GET     :urn/manifest/:derivativeurn](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/) endpoint with `Range` headers.

Comment: Thanks Petr, we will look into this option as file size is always an issue